# canvas image does not have changed css filter values

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, filter, html2canvas

change original image saturation

```
img.css('filter', 'saturate(0%)');
```

create canvas

```
$('#btnsave').on('click', function(){
    html2canvas($('#cins')[0]).then((canvas) => {
        $('#res').append(canvas);
    });
});
```

resulting image does not have new saturation value, but the original one
the same is with `hue` filter

how can I get canvas image with new css filter values ?

Comment: When is `img.css('filter', 'saturate(0%)');` called? Where is `img` coming from?

Comment: @Sumit - `img`is a standard image inside a div. `img.css...` is called before `btnsave` click

Comment: Where is `img` in the DOM? Is it at all related to the canvas code?

Comment: @Sumit - yes, it is inside `cins` div - which is entire related to canvas

Comment: Can you try adding the `saturate(...)` property with external/inline CSS, outside of JS? Does that work?

Comment: @Sumit - I tried just now, the same result. Seems html2canvas cannot recognize css filters

Comment: Did you [check the documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features) that clearly states css `filter` is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas does not support css filter properties. For the list of supported properties visit this link https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features